# Gitolite: wild repo overrides

Tags: gitolite

I'd like to enable wild repos except for one subrepo. For example:

```
repo proj/..*
    C       =   @ops
    RW+     =   @all

repo proj/secret
    RW+     =   bob
```

I'd like to make sure that only Bob has access to proj/secret but others can create all the other repos they want. Is that possible? Would the second repo definition overwrite the first one?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to configure the overwrite as a "wild repo" as well, this is described in the cookbook as [making exceptions for specific instances of a wild repo](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook#making-exceptions-for-specific-instances-of-a-wild-repo).
So using a regex for the 2nd repo should do it:

```
repo proj/..*
    C       =   @ops
    RW+     =   @all

repo proj/secre[t]
    RW+     =   bob
```